# ReSharper template macro for method return type

Tags: .net, templates, macros, resharper

I can't seem to find a way to insert the method return type in a ReSharper 5 macro. Can this be done?

For example, I have the following template:

```
Contract.Ensure(Contract.Result<$RESULTTYPE$>() != null);
```

I would like `$RESULTTYPE$` to be automatically filled with the data type of the current method, but I can't find a macro that would do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go:

*(I updated the link)*

http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/10/14/templates-galore-extending-functionality-with-macros/

Comment: link is fixed, unfortunately code no longer works (ver #8). Incorrect reference DLLs for example.